# How can I get zip_stat_t for large files

Tags: c, sizeof, strlen, libzip

For small files I can get the the `zip_stat_t` information, but if its a file 40Mb big I can't.

```
zip_stat_t info;
zip_stat_index(zipfile, 544, ZIP_FL_ENC_GUESS, &info);
printf("%s\n", info.name);
```

eg printing `info.name` is segfaulting for large files eg 40mb file. A 2Mb file will open with no problems. How can I get the size of `info.name`, for example since it it seems the info struct isn't being stored properly in RAM?

If I do `printf(strlen(info.name))` it results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: First suggestion would be to check the return value of zip_stat_index.  _"-1 is returned and the error information in archive is set to indicate the error"_  ([from here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/zip_stat_index)).

Comment: zip_stat_index is returning 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you experience is probably a failure of the *info* retrieval, so that the `name` field was invalid causing the segfault. The documentation doesn't mention size limits like those you experience.

To avoid this behavior is recommended to check the return value of [`zip_stat_index()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/zip_stat_index):

> Upon successful completion 0 is returned. Otherwise, -1 is returned and the error information in **archive** is set to indicate the error.

```
if (zip_stat_index(zipfile, 544, ZIP_FL_ENC_GUESS, &info) == 0 )
{
    printf("%s\n", info.name);
}
```

Why did the index retrieval fail? Possibly the `index` provided to the function (in your case `544`) is not present in the archive. In order to prevent this kind of *"not found index"* issues you can obtain the index of a given file using [`zip_name_locate ()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/zip_name_locate) function:

```
int zip_name_locate(struct zip *archive, const char *fname, int flags);
```

which returns either the index of `fname` within `archive` or `-1` if the file is not found.

Alternatively you can just use `zip_stat()` instead of `zip_stat_index()` which saves one step as it allows to ask for a file name as a parameter:

```
int zip_stat(struct zip *archive, const char *fname, int flags, struct zip_stat *sb);
```

Comment: no the index is present, its just having error at the index with a file which is huge

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the zip_stat_t. The issue was a line between `printf()` and after instantiating `zip_stat_index`. May be that variable was messing with memory for the `zip_stat info`.I had to allocate its memory with malloc. It was `char variable[info.size]`, changed it to `char *variable = malloc(info.size)`

Comment: @BretJoseph I see. It sounded really strange to me that the filie size could affect libzip behavior. If you don't mind I'm going to leave the answer, as it could be helpful for other readers (who could actually have an unnoticed error due to the missing check on the return value).